# Проблема с запуском undetected_chromedriver на Linux(Gentoo)

Tags: python, linux

Я новичок в разработке на Python. И сейчас я столкнулся со следующей проблемой при запуске undetected_chromedriver на Linux(Gentoo).

Я использую undetected_chromedriver версия 3.1.5r4, Python версия 3.8.5

Создана переменная окружения, которая хранит ссылку на исполняемый файл chromedriver для Linux:
`export CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = '/path_to_chromedriver/node_modules/chromedriver/bin/chromedriver'`

########################################################################
Код скрипта на Python

`import undetected_chromedriver as UC_1`

```
UC_1.TARGET_VERSION = 100

options = UC_1.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = UC_1.Chrome(driver_executable_path = os.environ.get('CHROMEDRIVER_PATH'), options = options, service_log_path = dir_name + '/chromedriver.log', use_subprocess = True)
```

##########################################################################
При запуске указанного кода, возникает следующая ошибка(запуск скрипта производился с включенным logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)):

```
INFO:undetected_chromedriver.patcher:patching driver executable /path_to_chromedriver/node_modules/chromedriver/bin/chromedriver
DEBUG:uc:created a temporary folder in which the user-data (profile) will be stored during this
session, and added it to chrome startup arguments: --user-data-dir=/tmp/tmp_fypdc2_
DEBUG:uc:did not find a bad exit_type flag

Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ea_test.py", line 219, in <module>
    driver = UC_1.Chrome(driver_executable_path = os.environ.get('CHROMEDRIVER_PATH'), options = options, service_log_path = dir_name + '/chromedriver.log', use_subprocess = True)
  File "/path_to_env/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/undetected_chromedriver/__init__.py", line 392, in __init__
    browser = subprocess.Popen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1627, in _execute_child
    executable = os.fsencode(executable)
  File "/usr/lib/python-exec/python3.8/../../../lib/python3.8/os.py", line 806, in fsencode
    filename = fspath(filename)  # Does type-checking of `filename`.
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я ошибся? Как исправить данную ошибку?

Comment: @andreymal Суть следующая: 1. Я использую модуль undetected_chromedriver . При запуске python скрипта на Linux у меня появляется ошибка `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType`  2.  Ошибка проявляется во время запуска этой команды в скрипте `driver = UC_1.Chrome(driver_executable_path = os.environ.get('CHROMEDRIVER_PATH'), options = options, service_log_path = dir_name + '/chromedriver.log', use_subprocess = True)` 3. В чем причина этой ошибки мне не понятно.  P.S.: Написал в кратко, чтобы сразу описать проблемную точку

Comment: @Mikhail нужно не суть, а перевести сам вопрос. Цитирую: На [Stack Overflow на русском](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/) вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь [Stack Overflow на английском](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @insolor Спасибо за коммент, только сейчас увидел , что запрос сделан в сегменте RU (привык читать на eng). Добавил описание на русском